# How to set up the scripts to run conditionally in package.json?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, package.json

I have a React project which requires Node.js to build it using Webpack.
I have 2 Node.js versions installed locally, 16 and 18. Is there a way in which I can detect the version while running package.json and conditionally execute the script?

If Node -v = 16
I want to execute below,

```
      "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "webpack --progress --mode production --dev",
    "build:prod": "lingui add-locale en && lingui extract --clean && lingui compile && webpack --mode production" 
    },
```

If Node -v = 18 then,

```
"scripts": {
    "build:dev": "SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && webpack --progress --mode production --dev",
    "build:prod": "SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && lingui add-locale en && lingui extract --clean && lingui compile && webpack --mode production" 
    },
```

Comment: Is there a reason to do this directly in `package.json` rather than in a separate build script in bash? The contents in quotes are passed to a shell anyway, so while you can put a conditional in there inline, it's starting to get unwieldy anyway.

Comment: It is better to have it in a single line for readability.

Comment: Maybe it's better to go full-reductionism and use `engines` (https://www.marcusoft.net/2015/03/packagejson-and-engines-and-enginestrict.html) to limit Node.js versions that can be used with the project, and default to Node 18 instead of introducing hacks for different versions?

Answer (score 2):

You may define a `setoptions` command, which does the check and if the condition is satisified execute the additional command. Then you can run `setoptions` before your other commands. E.g.:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "setoptions": "node -v | grep 'v18' && echo A",
    "command": "npm run setoptions; echo B"
  }
}
```

If you run `npm run command` and you have node 18, then both `echo A` and `echo B` will be performed. Otherwise, only `echo B` will be performed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to name these two different commands differently first like `"build:dev-16"` and `"build:dev-18"`. Then you write an conditional one line script.

Then write a script like

```
"scripts" : {
"build:dev-condition" : "[ \"`nvm --version`\" == \"v16.15.4\" ] && \"`npm run build:dev-16`\" || [ \"`nvm --version`\" == \"v18.15.4\" ] && \"`npm run build:dev-16`\""
}
```

You can do the same for `"build:prod"` versions as well.

Then write a prod script like

```
"scripts" : {
"build:prod-condition" : "[ \"`nvm --version`\" == \"v16.15.4\" ] && \"`npm run build:prod-16`\" || [ \"`nvm --version`\" == \"v18.15.4\" ] && \"`npm run build:prod-16`\""
}
```

**Important: make sure you use the correct version that shows in the console!**